# How to perform connectivity tests from Azure App Service to SMTP server hosted in on-premise environment?

Tags: azure, smtp, azure-appservice

I have a application developed using asp.net core 3.1, Angular 9, Azure SQL. This application is hosted in Azure via App Service. In this implementation, I have to use SMTP server to send mails which is hosted in on-premise environment. I want to perform a connectivity test from Azure App Service to SMTP Relay Service hosted in on-premise environment.

Can anyone help me to know are there any guidelines to perform the connectivity test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a Kudu console command, something like: `tcpping smtp.myserver.com:25` should be enough to tell you if you have basic connectivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris Butler for your response. It helped me to resolve the issue :)